# How to load lots of icons into ListView quickly from files dragged & dropped?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

I would like to load the icons from multiple files dragged onto a listview and some of the information of those files, but the process is going very slow.

In my test, a list of 381 files dragged (some are not exe so those are skipped in my code), takes over 2 minutes to load the icon from the file, and add them to the listview.

Following is condensed version of my code :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView1.DragEnter += ListView1_DragEnter;
        listView1.DragDrop += ListView1_DragDrop;
        listView1.LargeImageList = new ImageList() { ImageSize = new Size( 64, 64) };
        listView1.SmallImageList = new ImageList();
        listView1.AllowDrop = true;
    }

    private void ListView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] values = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            Convert.IconExtractor i = new Convert.IconExtractor();
            foreach (var v in values)
            {
                var info = new FileInfo(v);
                if(info.Extension.ToLower() == ".exe")
                {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
                    listView1.LargeImageList.Images.Add(i.Extract(info.FullName, Convert.IconSize.Large));
                    listView1.SmallImageList.Images.Add(i.Extract(info.FullName, Convert.IconSize.Small));
                    item.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(info.FullName);
                    item.ImageIndex = listView1.SmallImageList.Images.Count -1;
                    item.Tag = info.FullName;
                    listView1.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
            listView1.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void ListView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
        }
    }
```

The method used for extraction is pasted here for convenience :

```
    public enum IconSize
    {
        Small,
        Large
    }

    public class IconExtractor
    {

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //
        // Description: Extracts the icon associated with any file on your system.
        // Author: WidgetMan http://softwidgets.com
        //
        // Remarks...
        //
        // Class requires the IconSize enumeration that is implemented in this
        // same file. For best results, draw an icon from within a control's Paint
        // event via the e.Graphics.DrawIcon method.
        //
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        private const int SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
        private const int SHGFI_SMALLICON = 0x1;

        private const int SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;
        private struct SHFILEINFO
        {

            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public int iIcon;

            public int dwAttributes;
            [VBFixedString(260), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]

            public string szDisplayName;
            [VBFixedString(80), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]

            public string szTypeName;
        }
        [DllImport("shell32", EntryPoint = "SHGetFileInfoA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]

        private static extern int SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, int dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, int ByValcbFileInfo, int uFlags);

        public IconExtractor()
        {
        }

        public System.Drawing.Icon Extract(string File, IconSize Size)
        {
            SHFILEINFO aSHFileInfo = default(SHFILEINFO);
            int cbFileInfo = 0;
            int uflags = 0;
            System.Drawing.Icon Icon = default(System.Drawing.Icon);

            switch (Size)
            {
                case IconSize.Large:
                    uflags = SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON;
                    break;
                default:
                    uflags = SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_SMALLICON;
                    break;
            }

            cbFileInfo = Marshal.SizeOf(aSHFileInfo);

            SHGetFileInfo(File, 0, ref aSHFileInfo, cbFileInfo, uflags);

            Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(aSHFileInfo.hIcon);

            return Icon;
        }

        public System.Drawing.Icon Extract(string File)
        {
            return this.Extract(File, IconSize.Small);
        }

    }
}
```

What can I do to make this process quick.  The concept is to make a quick launcher for multiple applications.

Also of note, while this process is happening, the drag-collection icon is still 'hung' on windows explorer until the drag & drop task has completed fully (looped through all the files).

Here is a rough draft to give a visual of the application:

[image: desktop launcher]

(yes, i know the icons extracted look like crap as well, but I think that is a separate issue from the slow issue I am having)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is **not** to load all 381 icons in one step, particularly if the items are not visible.  Load them on demand as items are scrolled into view, of if the view is large enough, load them in the background using your threading/task/concurrency technology of choice.

That's what Windows does.

To speed up loading, you may want to use the **System Image List** which would most likely benefit from caching.  Here's some code for getting the large icon.  Just change `size` to be `SHGFI_ICON` for your use.

```
public static Icon GetLargeIcon(string FileName, bool jumbo, bool useFileAttributes=false)
{
    var shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();


    uint flags;
    flags = SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX;

    if (useFileAttributes) 
    {
        flags |= SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES;
    }

    var res = SHGetFileInfo(FileName, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, ref shinfo, (uint) Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo), flags);
    if (res == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        throw (new FileNotFoundException());
    }

    var iconIndex = shinfo.iIcon;

    // Get the System IImageList object from the Shell:
    var iidImageList = new Guid("46EB5926-582E-4017-9FDF-E8998DAA0950");

    IImageList iml;
    var size = jumbo
        ? SHIL_JUMBO 
        : SHIL_EXTRALARGE;
    var hres = SHGetImageList(size,  iidImageList, out iml); 
    if (hres != 0)
    {
        throw (new Exception("Error SHGetImageList"));
    }

    IntPtr hIcon;
    const int ILD_TRANSPARENT = 1;
    hres = iml.GetIcon(iconIndex, ILD_TRANSPARENT, out hIcon);

    var icon = Icon.FromHandle(hIcon);
    icon = icon.Clone() as Icon;
    var bm = icon.ToBitmap();
    DestroyIcon(hIcon);

    return icon;
}
```

Comment: These are items dragged to the window. Also, I have no problem seeing all 381 items with icons in windows explorer at once.  Instantly.  :)

Comment: I got it the first time without you needing to bold "not".  I think what you missed is that even if I load them in multiple steps -- it is still going to take a ridiculous amount of time to get all the icons and information displayed.  Windows Explorer displays them all *instantly* and if you slow it down, you can see windows also does them 1 at a time, but a whole lot faster.  381 icons loaded from files in 0.0001 second versus  381 icons loaded from files in 200 seconds.

Comment: @SanuelJackson I suggest you carefully re-read [what it was I actually changed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38649474/revisions) w/o the attitude.   Being an experienced _Windows Shell Developer_, I can assure you there is a significant time difference in displaying icons for a folder showing say 1000 **Word files** and the time taken to display icons for a folder showing 1000 different **application executables**, each with their own application icon.  **File type icon handlers are not the same as application icon handlers**. Hence why _"Windows Explorer displays them all instantly"_

Comment: Not giving "attitude", I was clarifying as it seems you overlooked what I stated.  The real problem here is each icon fetch is taking between 1 and 15 seconds per file (just tested).  Regarding applications, the exact same files are displayed completely in windows explorer with their icons -- not using something mystical or different aka, the test case of files is the exact same, and yes, I can see all 381 application icons in one view on my screen which takes windows explorer less than 1 second to display ALL

Comment: It is clear, the code above to read the icon from the file is painfully slow. So being a ~Windows Shell Developer~ perhaps you are familiar with the problem.  I am also aware that on very large lists, the icons are paged off-screen.

Comment: @SanuelJackson Windows has an icon cache, yours doesn't.  You could always make one.  Dictionary; database...

Comment: I have the icon cache disabled.  no thumbs.db or iconcache.db for me thanks.

Comment: @SanuelJackson thumbs.db et al is not what I am talking about.  See update for potential speed improvement

Comment: As an aside tho, SHGetFileInfo does use the cache, so in the statement that my program doesn't cache, you are partially correct.  It doesn't, but windows does and use of SHGetFileInfo takes advantage of it where it is located.  The drawing of the icons in windows explorer is still much faster and linear, so there is definitely something else going on -- a better way. (also of note, subsequent drag & drop operations of the same files in fresh launch and build of the application is faster.  the first time is very slow)

Comment: @SanuelJackson Incorrect. If your app were using the OS cache directly or indirectly, then it would follow that your app would always be as fast as Windows Explorer which, going by your comments, clearly isn't the case.  Therefor no OS caching utilisation.